# C++ data structure list, erro in my code

Tags: c++, list, data-structures

Hello i tried to compile my code but i get acess violation error. Im trying to make an agenda that i can insert values using a list. What is the error in my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct ap_agenda{
    char *name;
    char *telefone;
    struct ap_agenda *proximo;
};

void init(ap_agenda* lista){
    lista = NULL;
}

void insere(char *nome, char *telefone, ap_agenda* lista){
    ap_agenda *p;
    p = (ap_agenda*) malloc(sizeof(ap_agenda*));
    p->name = nome;
    p->telefone = telefone;

    if(lista == NULL){
        lista = p;
    }else{
        lista->proximo = p;
    }
}

void imprime(ap_agenda *lista){
    cout << lista[0].name << endl;
}

int main(){
    ap_agenda agenda;

    init(&agenda);
    insere("test","123456",&agenda);
    imprime(&agenda);

    system("pause");
}
```

Thanks !

Hello, thanks for the answers! I changed my code and now its "working" but when i try to print the list, its jump one line.

```
void insere(std::string nome, std::string telefone, ap_agenda* lista){
ap_agenda *p = new ap_agenda;

p->name = nome;
p->telefone = telefone;
p->proximo = NULL;

if(lista == NULL){
    lista = p;
}else{
    while(lista->proximo != NULL)
        lista = lista->proximo;

    lista->proximo =  p;
    }
}

void print(ap_agenda* lista){
    ap_agenda *p;
    for(p=lista; p!=NULL; p=p->proximo)
        cout << p->name.c_str() << endl;
}
```

The output is:
    [blankline]
    test1
    test2

Comment: Run it in a debugger, see in which line the program crashes and post it here.

Comment: Besides the incorrect `malloc`, look into `std::list` (or `std::forward_list`). There is no need to reinvent the wheel and hand-implement linked lists in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The access violation probably comes from your call to `insere` which isn't working like you think it does.

```
int main(){
    ap_agenda agenda; //<-- local variable lives on the stack

    init(&agenda); //<-- passes the address of the local variable
```

When this is passed to init:

```
void init(ap_agenda* lista){ // lista is a temporary variable that contains a
                             // copy of the address
    lista = NULL; //<-- this overwrites the value in the temporary variable.
} // when this function returns, the temporary variable is destroyed.
```

At this point `agenda` had not been modified or initialized in any way. Now you pass the address of `agenda` off to `insere`.

```
    insere("test","123456",&agenda);
```

`insere` is defined

```
void insere(char *nome, char *telefone, ap_agenda* lista){
    ap_agenda *p;
    p = (ap_agenda*) malloc(sizeof(ap_agenda*)); // you allocate a new `ap_agenda`
                                                 // pointer. not enough for a struct
    p->name = nome; // initialize name (probably ok but not what you expect)
    p->telefone = telefone;  // initialize telefone (possible access violation)

    if(lista == NULL){ // since lista is the address of a stack variable it won't
                       // be NULL here
        lista = p;
    }else{
        lista->proximo = p; // this sets the allocated struct to the `proximo` member
                            // of the stack variable that was passed in
    }
}
```

Note that when this returns, `nome` and `telefone` of the stack variable `agenda` have not been initialized.

```
    imprime(&agenda);
```

When the address of the stack variable `agenda` is passed to `imprime` it tries to print the value of `name` which has not been initialized.

```
void imprime(ap_agenda *lista){
    cout << lista[0].name << endl; // possible access violation
}
```

If instead, you passed in the `proximo` member of `agenda` which was initialized in `insere` you would see the `name` value printed.

```
    imprime(agenda->proximo);
```

However, as others have pointed out, there are a lot of other issues in this code.

Answer (score 4):

It would be nice to see the actual compiler error to see which line is causing the problem.

Without the compiler output, I  might guess that the issue is with

```
p = (ap_agenda*) malloc(sizeof(ap_agenda*));
```

which should probably be

```
p = (ap_agenda*) malloc(sizeof(ap_agenda));
```

or, even better,

```
p = new ap_agenda;
```

because, at the moment, you are only malloc()ing enough size for a pointer, not for the actual struct.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple errors - first off you're not writing C++ code, but C code.

```
void init(ap_agenda* lista){
    lista = NULL;
}
```

initializes to `NULL` the temporary `lista`. Outside, `lista` doesn't change.

That aside:

```
ap_agenda *p;
p = (ap_agenda*) malloc(sizeof(ap_agenda*));
```

allocates memory only the size of a pointer, not the object. And you use `malloc` instead of `new`. Awful.

You also never free the memory.

**Read a good C++ book!!!**

Comment: Agreed, here is a link some recommended books by the SO community http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 0):

```
 p = (ap_agenda*) malloc(sizeof(ap_agenda*));
```

here you allocate the size of the pointer, not of the structure !!!
so any access to p->xxx may lead to a memory access error.

```
p = (ap_agenda*) malloc(sizeof(ap_agenda));
```

would solve your problem i guess